# ssh remote command with wildcard

Tags: ssh, wildcard, remote-access

My goal is to get all IP addresses logging into my web server, by checking access log files:

```sh
$ ls -la /var/log/nginx/access.log*
/var/log/nginx/access.log
/var/log/nginx/access.log1
/var/log/nginx/access.log2
...
...
```

Running the command above locally works:

```sh
$ sudo grep loging /var/log/nginx/access.log*
```

But when I'm trying to run from a remote host

```sh
$ ssh remote-server 'sudo grep login /var/log/nginx/access.log*'
```

It returns:

```sh
grep: /var/log/nginx/access.log*: No scuh file or directory
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's not really related to nginx or grep, but indeed to SSH and wildcard. I just tried `ssh remote 'echo *'` and it seems to work. Are you sure the directory and files **do** exist? Is your remote shell's globbing option enabled?

Comment: yes files do exist. globbing option is enabled (tested with set -f and set +f and ls *)

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 2):

One possibility I have found is calling command through bash as an example:

```
ssh user@host '/bin/bash -c "grep /etc/*"'
```

Actually, it is not a `ssh` issue, the problem is with `sudo` which takes argument literally, check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355656/how-to-use-shell-wildcards-with-sudo).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the asterisk?

```
ssh remote-server 'sudo grep login /var/log/nginx/access.log\*'
```

Comment: Yes. same thing, No such file.

Answer (score 0):

When I try it, this works:

$ ssh remote 'ls -ld temp.*'
drwxrwxr-x. 2 me me 4096 Nov 15 07:43 temp.1

For some reason, this also works even though I would have believed that the double quotes are supposed to cause the '*' to be interpreted on the local side:

$ ssh remote "ls -ld temp.*"
drwxrwxr-x. 2 me me 4096 Nov 15 07:43 temp.1

These also work:

$ ssh remote 'ls -ld "temp."*'
drwxrwxr-x. 2 me me 4096 Nov 15 07:43 temp.1

$ ssh remote "ls -ld "temp."*"
drwxrwxr-x. 2 me me 4096 Nov 15 07:43 temp.1